# How to start tomcat server manually

Tags: tomcat7

I installed tomcat 7 in my windows 7.Then ran C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\binstartup.bat,one window will open for 1 second and closes.when i hit http //localhost/8080 ,its not dsiplaying anything.I just checked C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\conf/server.xml and port is 8080.

Can somebody help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Read RUNNING.txt and create C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\bin\setenv.bat file that sets JRE_HOME (or JAVA_HOME) path for Tomcat.

Sample from Tomcat 7 RUNNING.txt file using Java 6 JRE:

```
set "JRE_HOME=%ProgramFiles%\Java\jre6"
exit /b 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set **Java_Home** in **Cataline.bat** first in order to run TomCat server.

**Additional Information for running project using Tomcat Server.**

You can **cd** into the folder where **tomcatXX/bin** is through command line and run "run startup". So, when you , run startup on command line it tries to run script from startup.bat file, probably it crashed because port to be used by TomCat to run server is already in use. If you try to point your url to **localhost:8080**, if TomCat's home page appears, that would be because your server is already running. You should ideally also try to point to **Windows -> Preference -> Runtime Environment**. Check if Tomcat server is added in list under **Server Runtime Environment** window, if not try to add that server by clicking **Add** button, and trying to locate where Tomcat/bin is stored. If that still doesn't help, I would suggest you to also try right clicking a project on your IDE then click **Run As**, then click **Run Configuration**, it will give you option to run application using TomcatServer. List of servers will be found on left side of **Run Configuration** window.